# Does strlen have any side effect?

Tags: c++, c

I know, or better I suppose, that strlen() is fairly simple function, but for some reason, when I want to use it in one my function, it will corrupt the program. I have no idea why it's happening, because the results from strlen are correct, but the program as a whole doesn't work if strlen is included. To be specific, this part of code is causing trouble:

```
int random1 = strlen(objectNameValue);
int random2 = strlen(PA_type_value);
int random3 = strlen(attributeValue);
printf("length of objectNameValue: %d, PA_type_value: %d, attributeValue: %d", random1, random2, random3);
```

My program is actually a simple LDAP server and I'm trying to send some data - those variables (attributeValue), for example, when I put this part of code to comments, it works perfectly. But if I leave it there, sent data are not correct, and I have really no idea how strlen can affect them. Funny is that strlen is actually printing correct results.

To specify a bit more, those three variables in strlen are all of type char[] and all have /0 at the end. Can anyone help?

So, after request in comments, here is a closer look:
Basically, in very minimal way, this is something I'm doing:

```
char message_out[1024];
bzero(message_out, 1024);
char objectNameValue[1024];
strcpy(objectNameValue,"cn=");
char PA_type_value[5] = {'u', 'i', 'd'};
strcat(Message_out, objectNameValue);
strcat(Message_out, PA_type_value);
```

But sometimes I'm not putting the fixed characters into string, but another string for example., and I need to find out how big that string is, because I need to count total lengths of the message_out. I always watch out for strings, to be big enough, to be initialized with zeroes.

Output is this:

Length of objectNameValue: 12, PA_type_value: 3, attributeValue: 8

Comment: `strlen` has no side effects.  If you're seeing it cause this kind of issue, it implies you're invoking **undefined behaviour** elsewhere in your code.  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: is it possible one of those strings isn't null-terminated?

Comment: even if it was, it would crash right away, and wouldn't have a "delayed effect" like with undefined writes. your program bug is not because of strlen.

Comment: "strlen is actually printing correct results"  --> yet the post lacks even that output of `printf()`.  Hmmm.

Comment: Basically, in very minimal way, this is something Im doing:


char message_out[1024]; 
bzero(message_out, 1024);
char objectNameValue[1024];
strcpy(objectNameValue,"cn=");
char PA_type_value[5] = {'u', 'i', 'd'};
strcat(Message_out, objectNameValue);
strcat(Message_out, PA_type_value);
But sometimes Im not putting the fixed characters into string, but another string f.e. and I need to find out how big that string is, because I need to count total lengths of the message_out. I always watch out for strings, to be big enough, to be inicialized with zeroes.

Comment: It lacks output, because I thougth that you can believe me in this :D It really prints correct results.

Comment: Please edit your question adding the relevant code instead of writing it in the comments section. Add the output too.

Comment: When Im unvoking undefined behaviour elsewhere, why it is always okay and it pops up only when strlen is used?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: Never knew, this is actually a thing. But can I ask you, whats the best way to solve such a problem? How to locate it?

Comment: as long as I know, char PA_type_value[5] = {'u', 'i', 'd'} will fill fourth and fifth byte with /0.

Comment: @martin, that's not correct. `PA_type_value[5] = {'u', 'i', 'd'}` leaves the fourth and fifth byte strictly alone.  Change your code to `PA_type_value[5] = {'u', 'i', 'd','\0'}` and I bet it works.

Comment: Adding and removing `strlen` changes the machine code which compiler produces.. If code has undefined behavior elsewhere, then the behavior can be, and often is, different for these different compiler outputs. For example, use of stack will be different, and contents of stack often affect what undefined behavior does.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: That's false. `char PA_type_value[5] = {'u', 'i', 'd'}` is absolutely guaranteed to set the remaining array elements to zero. This is one of the cornerstones of C and C++ aggregate initialization philosophy: all-or-nothing.

Comment: There just isn’t enough data here to answer. If you can create a minimal *complete* program which still fails, then we can help; otherwise, we can only offer general tips like “use a debugger” and “run it through Valgrind”.

Comment: `strcpy(objectNameValue,"cn=");` ... `Length of objectNameValue: 12` ??? I'm uncertain how a string of length 3 is "correct" when the length printed is 12. Please match the output you provide to the sample input/code you provide. As Daniel H. said, a minimal program demonstrating the issue would be helpful. See this: [mcve]

Comment: Do you have multiple threads in this app? If not - the reason is missing 0 at the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with how `strlen` finds the length. `strlen` iterates through all characters of an array of characters until it finds a terminal \0 character. If the array does not have this terminal character, the implementation could proceed out of the memory bounds of the array of characters you gave it and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: While the C standard does claim that calling a string function on an unterminated string can cause critical undefined behavior, I'm having trouble imagining a `strlen()` implementation that would perform a write…

Comment: @duskwuff - `strlen()` is unlikely to specifically do a write.   However, if there is no terminating zero, it is possible that it attempts to access the value at a non-existent location in memory (in which case, the memory management unit - implemented as circuitry in quite a few modern CPUs - may generate illegal access errors).

Comment: @Peter Right -- but that'd simply cause a crash, not the unexpected behavior described by the OP.